# Twig date function not working on custom field within node

Tags: 8, theming

Even if `content.field_my_date` contains a date like 2021-10-01, twigs date function outputs today's date when using `{{ content.field_my_date|date("M.d.Y") }}`. Simply printing `{{ content.field_my_date }}` to make sure the field isn't empty, outputs the correct date and label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you need convert field `field_my_date` form `2021-10-01` to timestamp

You can use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.2.x) to be convert it to timestamp

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;


/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */

function hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  if($display->bundle()=='node_type'){
    $field_date_timestamp = strtotime($entity->get('field_my_date')- >value);
    $build['field_my_date'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format(
    $field_date_timestamp, 'custom', 'M.d.Y');
  }
}
```

in file twig node tempalte `{{field_my_date}}`